# HowTo set Icon to Qt Application, created with Qt Visual Studio Add-in?

Tags: qt, qt4, ico

Here is what I have:

- Visual Studio 2008 (on 32-bit Windows XP)
- Qt libraries 4.6.2 for Windows (VS 2008, 194 MB)
- **Visual Studio Add-in (44 MB)**

After I installed all the software, I created simple **Qt Application** project, with Visual Studio: menu *File | New | Project...* and *Qt4 Projects | Qt Application*.

Build it, and here is the **question:** how to set application icon to my compiled exe file? I need to see specified ICO in explorer!

---

Old method with MyProject.pro not interested!!!

1. Create a .ico file with both 16x16 and 32x32-pixel versions of the icon (you can do this in Visual Studio).
2. Create a .rc file containing the following text:

   IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "myIcon.ico"
3. Add the following to your .pro file

   RC_FILE = myFile.rc
4. Run qmake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally, I have found the correct solution, here it is:

**Preamble**: You need Visual Studio Add-in already installed!

1. Open Visual Studio (or Visual C++)
2. Create new project from menu: *File | New | Project...* and select project type as *Qt4 Projects* and for example *Qt Application* from templates.
3. When the first dialog window will be shown, just click **Next >** button twice.
4. And finally in Generated Class tap the **Add default application icon (Windows only)** checkbox.

   [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7f87801fb9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7f87801fb9.png)
5. To finish process, just press **Finish**.

Project will create a default icon, with name {your_project_name}.ico. Replace it and have fun!

Comment: The hosted image no longer exists.  The image should have been in-lined and hosted on SO.  It has been a while, but can you fix it?

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me [VS2010, Qt Add-in 1.1.8], for an existing project:

As in the docs at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/appicon.html :

- Add icon file (myappico.ico) to source dir
- Create myapp.rc file with the line

  IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "myappico.ico"

[Of course, the file names are free to choose, as long as they are consistent]

- Right-click project, choose Add | Existing item... and pick the RC file
- Rebuild

Answer (score 2):

From official document, it says:
If you do not use qmake, the necessary steps are: first, run the rc program on the .rc file, then link your application with the resulting .res file.

I tryed several times, it should be done like below:
1. Add an ico resource file to your project;
2. rename the file "yourappico.ico";
3. rebuild your project to generate yourapp.res file;
4. link your application with the resulting .res file.
( Projects->Properties->Linker->Input->Assembly link resource )

Answer (score 2):

You could also load it in manually. Following approach works for me:

```
#include <QtGui/QIcon>

QIcon icon("Resources/appicon.ico");
QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();
window->setWindowIcon(icon);
window->show();
```

Put your .ico file inside the Resources-Folder of your VS-Project.

(oops, did not fully read the question, but I just leave the answer it anyway... ^^)

Answer (score -2):

Right click you project on Solution Explorer and using the "Add" option include your icon in the project. It will include your icon and setup a rc file for you.

Comment: No, your answer not a solution. It's like if some one ask "what is a cow?", other man answered: "Oh, it's like a cat, or like a dog, but big, or just fat"... I think you better to remove such an answer. It's not the best one, but thank you!

Comment: The icon shown in explorer is defined by the first icon resource in the solution. You need a resource file and it must be setup in some way - be it a .pro or by using the Solution Explorer context menu. I don't believe you can find a different answer. And, next time, be polite.

Comment: As you can see from my question, I set bold one of the lines: *Visual Studio Add-in (44 MB)*. If I created Qt Application project with **that** add-in, it doesn't generate, or even used pro-files. Every information it, if I'm not mistaken, store in MSVC solution file, but not in pro. So adding *RC_FILE = myFile.rc* in pro is impossible! I don't want be polite, when you stolen my **Tumbleweed** badge!!! :|